# Is there any maping between the AAL to Brodmann areas (BA)?

Tags: neuroimaging

I am trying to find any correspondence between BA6 (Premotor cortex) and AAL, but there are no information about it. Is there any equivalence table for Brodmann areas and other related anatomic labels?

Comment: I came across your question and I have the same problem. Have you found any answer by chance?